# javascript for gimmick cart only need javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cart

http://jsfiddle.net/mDayR/

If you check out that jsFiddle, All I am trying to do is when you click the Add To Cart button it will send the Items Name that you are adding to the cart inside the li elements. As well as updating the total price. This is a gimmick shopping cart for some online Ecart that everything is done manually since there is no access to php.

Say so I click on three items, Coke Cola $200, Pistol $600, and a baseball cap $500. Then I want the list to be like so

```
<ul>
<li>Coke Cola</li> 
 <li>Pistol</li>
  <li>Baseball Cap</li>
 </ul>
 <span>Total = $1300.00</span>
```

Please don't ask for me to check out shopping carts, this is a Gimmick cart for a user, this is to help their users to see how many points they will owe. No data will be processed except into a hidden form that the items will be pasted in as well.

Comment: your javAscript is not doing much, your selector is not correct it should be $(".points")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to create the list items on click and append them to the list.

Then add the points attribute to a total and then display that.

so

```
var theNewItem = '<li>' + itemName + '</li>';
$('.itemList').append(theNewItem);
runningTotal += points;
$('.totaler').html("$" + runningtotal.toFixed(2));
```

That should get you started

here is a corrected fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/mDayR/4/

personally since 'No data will be processed' I would suggest instead of a submit you use a button, then do your computations on the click handler of the button.

http://jsfiddle.net/mDayR/6/

one more fiddle with the button logic

http://jsfiddle.net/mDayR/10/ - can add item multiple times
http://jsfiddle.net/mDayR/11/ - can add item only once

Comment: How would I remove item? with the click of the <li> item?

Comment: yep, you can assign an onclick to the <li> item to get rid of it. http://jsfiddle.net/mDayR/14/